# Reading data from ethernet port using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, port, ethernet

I am trying to open an ethernet port to receive data using Qt libraries. Previously I was using libpcap library to do this work. `pcap_open_live("eth0", ... )` to open the ethernet port and `pcap_loop()` to collect the data.

Are there any similar functions in Qt libraries which does this work? If yes, can anyone explain how to use them.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at QNetworkAccessManager. It works on sockets instead of ports directly, but it should be able to do what you need.

Comment: Sorry, to be more explicit, in terms of how to use it, broadly speaking, you set it to "listen" on a TCP port, and then send a buffer at that port via whatever means your sender needs to. Then that writes to a buffer that is read in the QNetworkAccessManager as a QByteArray which can be converted into a string.